# Let $u = (2, 3, 1)$, $v = (1, 3, 0)$, and $w = (2, -3, 3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with this. Any help is appreciated.

Let $u = (2, 3, 1)$,  $v = (1, 3, 0)$, and $w = (2, -3, 3)$. Since $(1/2)u - (2/3)v - (1/6)w = (0, 0, 0)$ can we conclude that the set $\{u, v, w\}$ is linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Over the field $\mathbb{F}_7$, the inverse of $2$ is $4$, the inverse of $3$ is $5$, and the inverse of $6$ is itself. So we get 
$$
4u-2*5v-6w=0
$$
in this field.